# Spring Cloud Stream - JsonParseException when consuming messages

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm running two instances of Spring Cloud Stream application with Kafka binder.
One instance uses scs 3.1.3 version and produces messages using StreamBridge.

```
streamBridge.send("produceMessage-out-0", MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(message)
        .setHeader(PARTITION_KEY, partition)
        .setHeader("type", "MyMessage")
        .build());
```

The other one, instead, use scs 2.1.3 version and tries to consume messages produced by the first instance.

However, the consumer application log this error

```
{"stack_trace":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values\n at [Source: (byte[])\"0e67331703f9fecf-ce84870011cef91b-0\"; line: 1, column: 12]\r\
```

and other log of this type

```
Could not decode json type: application/json for key: contentType
```

or

```
Could not decode json type: MyMessage for key: type
```

I saw that errors concern headers.
I tried to set `headerMode` to `raw`, `none` and `embeddedHeader` into consumer's application.yaml. But with no result.

I also read this thread, seems to be similar to my problem.
[Could not decode json type for key: file_name in a Spring Cloud Data Flow stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155689/could-not-decode-json-type-for-key-file-name-in-a-spring-cloud-data-flow-stream)

But BinderHeaderMapper is deprecated into 2.1.3 and I cannot understand how to replace it.

Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Really? Nobody can help me?

Comment: Got any solution for this?